# How to show that this integral is finite?

Tags: integration, complex-geometry

For concreteness, let's assume the setting from [Explicit nowhere vanishing holomorphic volume form on quintic $3$-fold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337612/explicit-nowhere-vanishing-holomorphic-volume-form-on-quintic-3-fold) .
$f=x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4$ defines the smooth quartic surface $X:=Z(f) \subset \mathbb{CP}^3$.
On $X$ there exists a holomorphic volume form $\Omega \in \Omega^3(X, \mathbb{C})$.

Here is how to write $\Omega$:
on the affine chart $U_0:=\{x: x_0=1\}$ we consider the open and dense set $V_1 := \{x : \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \neq 0\}$.
Then $\Omega=\frac{dx_2 \wedge dx_3}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}}$ on $V_1$.
Explicitly:
on $U_0$ we have $x_1=\sqrt[4]{-1-x_2^4-x_3^4}$, where we can ignore the ambiguity in $\sqrt[4]{\cdot}$, because we are only interested in whether the following integral is finite and not in its exact value.
Therefore $\Omega=dx_2 \wedge dx_3 \cdot \frac{1}{4}(-1-x_2^4-x_3^4)^{-3/4}$.

I want to verify that the integral
$$
vol(X)
:=
\int_X \Omega \wedge \overline{\Omega}
=
\int_V \Omega \wedge \overline{\Omega}
\sim
\int_V |1+x_2^4+x_3^4|^{-6/4} \, vol_{\mathbb{C}^2}
$$
is finite.
(The $\sim$ means proportional. I think the two integrals are actually equal, but there may be a factor of $4$ or $\frac{1}{4}$ missing due my liberal use of $\sqrt[4]{\cdot}$.)
Here, $x_2, x_3$ are complex coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^2$.
I attempted to apply Fubini's theorem, reducing the calculation to a single slice orthogonal to $\{1+x_2^4+x_3^4=0\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$, but I couldn't solve it and wasn't able to verify that the theorem can be applied in this case anyway.